# NOT NULL columns in SQLite and error catching

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database that is being filled by user defined EditTexts. None of the edit texts should allow empty fields. I know that I can check for this with a couple simple if-statements: `if myEditText.getText().toString().equals("") // display error`. However I would perfer to use this opportunity to brush up on my SQLite and error catching (as demonstrated in my add method). **How would I go about altering the columns in the table below to `NOT NULL` and generating/catching an error when a user attempts to add/update with empty fields?**

My database table:

`db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE inventory (category TEXT, itemNum TEXT, quantity INTEGER, price REAL, image INTEGER, UNIQUE(category, itemNum) ON CONFLICT FAIL);");`

My add method:

... fill `ContentValues values`

```
try{
db.getWritableDatabase().insertWithOnConflict(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, DatabaseHelper.CATEGORY, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_FAIL);
fillItemNumbers();          
}
catch(SQLiteConstraintException e)
{
Toast
.makeText(MyActivity.this, etItemNum.getText().toString() + " already exists in " +     catSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString() +". Consider using Update.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
.show();            
}
```

My update method:

... fill `ContentValues values`

```
String[] args = {catSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), etItemNum.getText().toString()};
int rowsAffected = db.getWritableDatabase().update(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, DatabaseHelper.CATEGORY + "=? AND " + DatabaseHelper.ITEM_NUMBER + "=?" , args);
```

UPDATE:
I did a little digging and came up with this:

`db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE inventory (category TEXT NOT NULL, itemNum TEXT NOT NULL, quantity INTEGER NOT NULL, price REAL NOT NULL, image INTEGER NOT NULL, UNIQUE(category, itemNum) ON CONFLICT FAIL);");`

Is this what I am looking for? If so, how can I use this to my advantage (see above)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you can actually Alter Column Definition for table. I know you can Alter Table itself, like adding new Column to Table. You might need little trick to modify your database if there is lot of data in it that you want to preserve.

One way to it to create new table and try copying data to new table and afterwards remove old table and rename new Table. It's not most efficient way to do it but it'll get the job done though.

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

[image: 1]

**EDIT**

Here you go

```
CREATE TABLE inventory (category TEXT not null, itemNum TEXT not null, quantity INTEGER not null, price REAL not null, image INTEGER not null, UNIQUE(category, itemNum) ON CONFLICT FAIL);
```

**EDIT 2**
Try this

```
CREATE TABLE inventory (category TEXT not null ON CONFLICT FAIL, itemNum TEXT not null ON CONFLICT FAIL, quantity INTEGER not null ON CONFLICT FAIL, price REAL not null ON CONFLICT FAIL, image INTEGER not null ON CONFLICT FAIL, UNIQUE(category, itemNum) ON CONFLICT FAIL);
```

Comment: The table does not have anything in it but test rows atm. I can blow it away and rebuild it with no problem. This issue is that I am completely clueless as how to implement NOT NULL on the columns.

Comment: I'll test this out with blank fields and see if I can discover something about the error portion from my LogCat.

Comment: I just tested it out in-app. My database still has no problem gleefully accepting blank EditTexts as valid data.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html read **SQL Data Constraints**, you might have to set some conflict constraints also to raise errors.

Comment: Something I just realized is that `"" != null`. Is there another way of implementing this for a similar result or should I just stick to the Java-based solution?

Comment: I have been staring blankly at that page all day. Upon re-reading it I am thinking that some type of `CHECK` should be used to see if the strings inserted are empty or something along those lines.

Comment: I was thinking the same this, as what you are inserting might be an empty string which is not `NULL`.

Comment: the `SQLite` is not complaining because you are not inserting `NULL` values into database. when you call `myEditText.getText().toString()`, it returns the `String` and  `Empty String` `""` if noting is entered, not`NULL`. That's why database does not raise any flags on insertion.

Comment: I decided to go with a check in my Java code for blank EditTexts in my calls to add to and update the database. Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is set the columns to NOT NULL.

Then use

```
insertWithOnConflict(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues initialValues, int conflictAlgorithm)
```

and

```
updateWithOnConflict(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs, int conflictAlgorithm)`
```

There are several constants you can use for the conflictAlgorithm, depending on exactly what you want to happen.  If you want to simply not enter the data into the table, `CONFLICT_IGNORE` will do the trick.  If you want a return code letting you know so you can act on it (let the user know) then you might want `CONFLICT_FAIL`.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) for further information.

Hope this helps.