# need sqlite db to not accept null values

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, null

My sqlite db is accepting null values and I don’t know why. I have my Table as "Primary Key" and my columns as "Text Not Null". Db should not accept null, non-unique values and inserts greater than row 1.

DB:

```
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String sqlDataStore = "create table if not exists " +
        TABLE_NAME_CREDENTIALS + " ("+ BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key ,"

                    + COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME + " text not null unique,"
                    + COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD + " text not null unique);";


        db.execSQL(sqlDataStore);
    }


    public static boolean Login(String username, String password) {

        Boolean Login = true;
        Cursor c =  db.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_CREDENTIALS + " WHERE "
                        + COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME + " = '" + username +"' AND "+ COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD +" = '"+ password +"'" ,  null);
         if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                Login = false;
            }
            c.close();
            return Login;
    }
```

Insert Method:

```
         private void insertCredentials(RegDetails regDetails){

        LoginDB androidOpenDBHelper = new LoginDB(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB = androidOpenDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(LoginDB.COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME, rUsername);
        contentValues.put(LoginDB.COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD, rPasscode);

        long affectedColumnid = sqliteDB.insert(LoginDB.TABLE_NAME_CREDENTIALS, null, contentValues);

        if(affectedColumnid > 1){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Already Exist! Please login" + affectedColumnid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Credentials Saved! Please login" + affectedColumnid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        sqliteDB.close();
        finish();
    }   

  }
```

Comment: Where do `rUsername` and `rPassword` come from? If these are read from an EditText (or similar) then the blank value is not `null` but an empty String (`""`).

Comment: `if(affectedColumnid < 0){` `sqliteDB.insert()` returns `-1` if it can't insert.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the fact that you don't use ON CONFLICT FAIL described on the SQLite website: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

If you want an example of query, you can have a look at a previous question: [NOT NULL columns in SQLite and error catching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935991/not-null-columns-in-sqlite-and-error-catching)

Hope this will help you.

Side Note: for building long String, it is good practice to use a StringBuilder.

Comment: I disagree. Using `ON CONFLICT` is not required to enable the `not null` constraint, it merely provides a different way of handling the error after it has happened.